# NSIS installer remembering previous install directory

Tags: nsis

I've got a problem where the NSIS installer is remembering the previous install location of the product I want to install after the previous version of the product is installed.

I want to prevent this behavior ... so that the installer uses the default directory I specify in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution ... needed to remove `InstallDirRegKey` from my script.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/InstallDir_doesn%27t_work